# jumping location on google maps by gps. (inaccurate distance)

Tags: android, gps, distance, google-maps-api-2

my app should display the distance and location in real time when the user walked, but there are errors with my output. 
the distance did not start immediately but when it start it increase a lot until it slows down a bit. 
the red marker and blue dot should be together according to one example I've seen but they are separate in my app. both of them point my current location right?
both red marker and blue dot jumps around in a short time that i was not moving that is away from my true location. which i believe lead to the inaccuracy of the distance as well.

please see my output for more details

java code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

protected LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
Button btnStartMove,btnPause,btnResume,btnStop;
static double n=0;
Long s1,r1;
double dis=0.0;
Thread t1;
EditText userNumberInput;
boolean bool=false;
int count=0;

double speed = 1.6;
double lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,lat3,lon3,lat4,lon4;
double dist = 0;
TextView distanceText;
float[] result;
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES =1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 3000; //in milliseconds
boolean startDistance = false;
boolean firstTime = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    if(isGooglePlay())
    {
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    distanceText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distance);
    btnStartMove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);//start moving

    //prepare distance...........
    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");  
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    btnStartMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDistance = true;
//              lat3 = location.getLatitude();
//              lon3 = location.getLongitude();
        }
    });
    if(location!= null)
    {
        //Display current location in Toast
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Display current location in textview  
        //latitude.setText("Current Latitude: " + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())); 
        //longitude.setText("Current Longitude: " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

        //lat3 = location.getLatitude();
        //lon3 = location.getLongitude();
    }
    else if(location == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Location is null",    
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if(googleMap == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Getting map",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        googleMap =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayMap)).getMap();

        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

}

private void setUpMap() 
{
    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if(provider == null)
    {
        onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(myLocation != null)
    {
        onLocationChanged(myLocation);
    }       
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
}

private boolean isGooglePlay() 
{
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is available",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10).show();

    }
    return (false);

 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
    System.out.println("speed " + myLocation.getSpeed());
//      if(myLocation.getSpeed() > speed)
//      {
        //show location on map.................
        //Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        //Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        //Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //Show the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));

        //show distance............................

        if(startDistance == true)
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                      "Location has changed",    
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(myLocation != null)
                {
                    //latitude.setText("Current Latitude: " + String.valueOf(loc2.getLatitude())); 
                    //longitude.setText("Current Longitude: " + String.valueOf(loc2.getLongitude()));
                    float[] results = new float[1]; 
                    Location.distanceBetween(lat3, lon3, myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), results);
                    System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]);               

                    dist += results[0];            
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // adjust this as appropriate
                if(count==1)
                {
                    distanceText.setText(df.format(dist) + "meters");
                }
                    lat3=myLocation.getLatitude();
                    lon3=myLocation.getLongitude();
                    count=1;
              }

        }
        startDistance=true;
    //}


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
}}
```

[image]

[image]

there seem to be no way to solve my error.i was recommeded to use location.getSpeed but it returns 0.

Comment: your distance is 1 meter to detect and time is 3 seconds to update. do you consider it?

Comment: i thought about it. i wanted to update the distance for every 1 meter the minimum so it can be more accurate. so should i increase the timing? but even if i increase, it will still remains inaccurate..

Comment: A similar question to this was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274271/google-maps-location-keeps-jumping-between-my-real-location-and-0-6-miles-away

Comment: HI @Myst did you ever get a solution to this problem? I am having the exact same issue

Comment: I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991613/locationmanager-and-jumping-coordinates  Is there any solution?