# Google Maps - Location keeps jumping between my real location and 0.6 miles away (Random place)

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I've got Google Maps v2 running on my app, using a service to get the users location. Problem is the location keeps changing. It shows my real location for a bit, then jumps to a random location that I've never been to before.

I'm check GPS/Network lat/lng via the service and calling them in my maps class, where I then animate the camera to move to my location. I don't really know what's wrong, or where to start with this one.

Does anyone know what sort of problem this is? It's baffling to me.

I don't really know what code to post. The accuracy of the location via network is 1121m where as the accuracy of the location via GPS is around 31. I'm using a `LocationListener` and in the `onLocationChanged` is says it's using my network location, suddenly the accuracy improves, to 29m, then it suddenly goes back up to 1121m. This happens about every minute or so. Very odd behaviour. With GPS enabled, shouldn't that be the preferred choice anyway? Is there a way to set it to my preferred choice once it gets a fix?

My service gets it's information like this:

```
public Location getLocation() {
    Log.i("getLocation", "Get location called");
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        //Getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled and GPS is off.
            Log.d("NOT ENABLED", "PASSIVE PROVIDER");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            if (loc != null) {
                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                Log.i("PASSIVE_LOCATION", "Location: "+loc.toString());
            }
        }
        else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this); 
                loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (loc != null) {
                    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    Log.i("NETWORK_LOCATION", "Location: "+loc.toString());
                }
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (loc != null) {
                    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    Log.i("GPS_LOCATION", "Location: "+loc.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //check provider & accuracy
    Log.d("PROVIDER", loc.getProvider());
    Log.d("ACCURACY", Float.toString(loc.getAccuracy()));
    return loc;
```

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this solved itself. It was jumping between locations simply because of accuracy. Once GPS accuracy was better than network, it started updating via GPS.

I'm also stopping location updates once the accuracy is less than 30 in `onLocationChanged` so I have a bit more control and don't waste the users battery.

Comment: can you please tell us how to check the accuracy?

Comment: Hi! Please take a look at my code to help the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991613/locationmanager-and-jumping-coordinates

Comment: You can get accuracy from the onLocationChanged that you Override that looks something like public void onLocationChanged(Location location). You can see it comes with an object called location, you get accuracy using that object by calling location.getAccuracy( )